# How can I query recent 5 sticky posts on WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, blogs

I've tried using this code on loop, and it gives me just one post from the sticky posts:

```
<div id="content">
<ul class="disclosure table group">
<?php
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post__in'  => $sticky,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( isset($sticky[0]) ) {
?>

    <li style="text-align: justify; font-weight: 500; color: #b30404;">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color: #b30404;" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><span style="font-size: 15px;"><?php the_title(); ?> </span></a>
</li>
<?php } ?></ul></div>
```

and I want it showing 5. I have tried adding this line to the code but not working:

```
$sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 5 );
```

I need help on how I can make this code show 5 latest posts (only sticky posts). Or give me a code I can use that's will be a solution to my request. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

rsort( $sticky );

$sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 5 );

$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 ) );
```

try this

and remove this line `if ( isset($sticky[0]) ) {`

add this loop after the query

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        $the_query->the_post();

        the_title();
   }
}
```

Comment: Still not working. Or maybe I'm not using it the right way. Please can you help arranging it completely. Thanks a mllion

Comment: with the code you gave me, this is how I used it. But it's not working. It's still showing one post from the sticky posts and not 5.

Comment: <div id="content">
<ul class="disclosure table group">
<?php
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

rsort( $sticky );

$sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 5 );

$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 ) );
if ( isset($sticky[0]) ) {
?>

 <li style="text-align: justify; font-weight: 500; color: #b30404;">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color: #b30404;" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><span style="font-size: 15px;"><?php the_title(); ?> </span></a>
</li>
<?php } ?></ul></div>